# PHP startup mongo: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, mongodb, dll, installation, xampp

I am currently Using *xampp* for *PHP*. I installed *mongo_db(1.8.5)* in my system and also installed *xampp-1.8.1-VC9* in my system. In order to configure PHP for *mongoDB*, I have downloaded *php_mongo.dll*(tried both `VC9 thread safe` and `non-thread safe`) and pasted the *.dll* file in the *'../php/ext'* directory and also added `extension=php_mongo.dll` in the *php.ini* file.

Now when I try to start the *apache* in *xampp* it shows the following display eventhough *apache* is getting started.

```
PHP startup mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API : 20090626
PHP compiled with module API : 20100525
These options need to match.
```

Also my *.php* code to connect *Mongo* is not working. This means there is something wrong somewhere.

Where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have the right approach, but are copying the wrong DLL (see my answer below).  Also note that 1.8.x is now two major production release series behind (latest is 2.2.x).  If you're just getting started, it would be well worth starting with the 2.2 server as there are [many new features](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install an extension compiled for PHP 5.3 with PHP 5.4; the module API version needs to match the version of PHP.

If you download the [precompiled MongoDB PHP driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) from Github (eg. `php_mongo-1.2.12.zip` is the current stable version) it includes DLLs for multiple PHP versions (eg 5.2, 5.3, and 5.4).  You need to copy the correct DLL for your system and rename it php_mongo.dll.

You can determine the required version from the `phpinfo()` output on your system (or `php -i` from a command line).  Check the value for "Zend Extension Build".

For example:

```
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS,VC9
```

.. would indicate you should use the NTS (Non-threadsafe) DLL.

On 64-bit Windows, that would mean copying `php_mongo-1.2.12-5.4-vc9-nts-x86_64.dll` to `php_mongo.dll` in your PHP extension directory.

Comment: Thans @stennie. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks, helped me as well